# How do I use Bootstrap.Tabs from ember-bootstrap project correctly?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use the Bootstap.Tabs component to create some bootstrap tabs.

I've declared the tabs as follows:

```
{{view Bootstrap.Tabs
  contentBinding="App.tabsContent"
  selectionBinding="App.selection"}}
```

And I'm using the following code to set up the content for the tabs.

```
App.ready = function() {
  App.tabsContent= Ember.A([{value: "cred_app.associate_clients", title: "Associate clients"}, {value: "cred_app.facilities", title: "Facilities"}]);    
};
```

Using this I can successfully render the bootstrap tabs.. and the route name pops up in *App.selection*.

I just don't understand how to get the links working, so that controller will transition to the route. I'd also like to get the active tab get the correct css applied to it so that the tabs show which route is currently being displayed.

UPDATE:

I have implemented this using a more simplistic approach:

```
<ul class='nav-tabs'>
  {{#linkTo 'cred_app.associate_clients' model tagName='li' href=false}}
    {{#linkTo 'cred_app.associate_clients' model}}Client Hierachy{{/linkTo}}
  {{/linkTo}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:
(using my derived [Bootstrap.Tabs](https://github.com/pjlammertyn/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/packages/ember-bootstrap/lib/views/tabs.js) implementation)

```
{{#view Bootstrap.TabContainerView currentView="patient"}}
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {{#view Bootstrap.TabView value="patient"}}<a>Patient</a>{{/view}}
    {{#view Bootstrap.TabView value="visits"}}<a>Visits</a>{{/view}}
    {{#view Bootstrap.TabView value="contacts"}}<a>Contacts</a>{{/view}}
    {{#view Bootstrap.TabView value="sessions"}}<a>Sessions</a>{{/view}}
   </ul>
   {{#view Bootstrap.TabPaneView viewName="patient"}}
     {{render "patient"}}
   {{/view}}
   {{#view Bootstrap.TabPaneView viewName="visits"}}
     {{render "visits"}}
   {{/view}}
   {{#view Bootstrap.TabPaneView viewName="contacts"}}
     {{render "contacts"}}
   {{/view}}
   {{#view Bootstrap.TabPaneView viewName="sessions"}}
     {{render "sessions"}}
   {{/view}}
{{/view}}
```

or using the router:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  {{#view Bootstrap.TabItem item="patient"}}
    {{#linkTo "tab.patient" content}}Patient{{/linkTo}}
  {{/view}}
  {{#view Bootstrap.TabItem item="visits"}}
    {{#linkTo "tab.visits" content}}Visits{{/linkTo}}
  {{/view}}
  {{#view Bootstrap.TabItem item="contacts"}}
    {{#linkTo "tab.contacts" content}}Contacts{{/linkTo}}
  {{/view}}
  {{#view Bootstrap.TabItem item="sessions"}}
    {{#linkTo "tab.sessions" content}}Sessions{{/linkTo}}
  {{/view}}
</ul>
{{outlet}}
```

the magic is done by the Bootstrap.TabItem, it gets the active state from the linkTo helper

```
Bootstrap.TabItem = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['active'],

  activeChanged: function () {
    var self = this;
    Ember.run.next(this, function () { //delay
      if (!self.isDestroyed) {
        self.set('active', self.get('childViews.firstObject.active'));
      }
    });
  }.observes('childViews.firstObject.active') //get the active state from the linkTo helper
});
```

now you only need a router, something like this:

```
App.Router.map(function (match) {
  ...
  this.resource('tab', { path: '/tab' }, function () {
    this.route('patient');
    this.route('visits');
    this.route('contacts');
    this.route('sessions');
  });
  ...
});
```

a jsFiddle might help

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. The only problem is that the currently active tab is not highlighted using this solution. Also.. Your solution is based on your fork of ember-bootstrap. Is it not possible to get these results with the standard library? I couldn't find a way and have used a manual solution in the interim, but its not very DRY as I keep on repeating the tab structure.

Comment: The active tab is highlighted. In the 1st samle this is done by checking the tabsContainer.currentView property (see the code). In the second example you need to set the selectedTab property of the tabcontroller in the patients, visits, contacts and sessions route! There is another possibility, that I will supply as an additional example.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at *Bootstrap for Ember*

It fully supports Pills & Tabs:

https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember

Showcase: ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember